# VSCode não mostra a pasta node_modules no Explorer

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, ide

Após a instalação do Express notei que o Vscode na sua interface não mostra mais a pasta dentro do projeto na aba Explorer, muitas vezes preciso alterar algo no node_modules e sou obrigado a abri-la em uma nova janela. Deixarei Screenshots em anexo. Como faço para resolver este problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entre nas preferências do `VSCODE` e verifique se existe a opção `**/node_modules` no bloco `File:Exclude`. Se existir remova-o.

Caminho:

`CTRL+,` -> Pesquise `Exclude` -> Deve ser o primeiro bloco retornado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado, resolvido!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, pode acontecer também do Visual Studio Code ocultar arquivos e pastas elencadas no conteúdo do arquivo .gitignore.

***Configurações → Recursos → {{Explorador}}****
Desmarque →   *Explorer : Exclude Git Ignore. ou revise o conteúdo de .gitignore.*

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).